# Capturing parts of string using regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r

I have these strings:

```
myseq <- c("ALM_GSK_LN_06.ID","AS04_LV_06.ID.png","AS04_SP_06.IP.png")
```

What I want to do is to capture parts of the sequence

```
ALM_GSK  LN  ID
AS04     LV  ID
AS04     SP  IP
```

I tried this but failed:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(myseq, "([A-Z]+)_(LN|LV|SP)_06\\.([A-Z]+)")
```

Which produces:

```
     [,1]           [,2]  [,3] [,4]
[1,] "GSK_LN_06.ID" "GSK" "LN" "ID"
[2,] NA             NA    NA   NA  
[3,] NA             NA    NA   NA  
>
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Looks like it might be a job for `strsplit()`.

Comment: @voidHead: I don't think so. `ALM_GSK` form a single entity of first part. If we use strsplit it'll be hard to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Here is a small adjustment:

```
str_match(myseq, "(.+)_(LN|LV|SP)_06\\.([A-Z]+)")[, -1]
```

produces:

```
     [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] "ALM_GSK" "LN" "ID"
[2,] "AS04"    "LV" "ID"
[3,] "AS04"    "SP" "IP"
```

Yours doesn't work because your first token matches neither numbers or underscores, which you need for "AS04" (numbers) and "ALM_GSK" (underscores).

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression incorrectly matches the prefix because `[A-Z]+` only matches letters. To fix this simply change the first group to a greedy operator such as `(.+)`, here is another solution.

```
library(gsubfn)
myseq <- c('ALM_GSK_LN_06.ID', 'AS04_LV_06.ID.png', 'AS04_SP_06.IP.png')
strapply(myseq, '(.+)_([A-Z]+)[^.]+\\.([A-Z]+)', c, simplify = rbind)

#      [,1]      [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "ALM_GSK" "LN" "ID"
# [2,] "AS04"    "LV" "ID"
# [3,] "AS04"    "SP" "IP"
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally stealing @hwnd's regex but in a **tidyr**/**dplyr** approach:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
data_frame(myseq) %>%
    extract(myseq, c('A', 'B', 'C'), '(.+)_([A-Z]+)[^.]+\\.([A-Z]+)')

##         A  B  C
## 1 ALM_GSK LN ID
## 2    AS04 LV ID
## 3    AS04 SP IP
```